# In c++, how do I build a data structure with objects as member variables?

Tags: c++, object, data-structures, constructor

I recently started research that involved coding in cpp which I'm completely new to, and am having trouble with a bunch of stuff:

1. Default constructors
2. Creating a data structure with objects as member variables.

My program setup needs to be like this:

- I need to create a data structure that has one of its member variables as an array of Wave objects: Wave[ ]
- The Wave is actually read from a wave file(My code is linked to some external libraries to do this)
- Each Wave has a GPS object.
- Each GPS object have ~15 member variables of type int or double

This is what my GPS.hpp class looks like -

```
 #ifndef GPS_HPP_
    #define GPS_HPP_

    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include "pulsereader.hpp"
    #include "pulsewriter.hpp"

    class GPS{

    public:
      //possible parameters
      double gpsTime;
      double xAnchor, yAnchor, zAnchor;
      double xTarget, yTarget, zTarget;
      double xDeviation, yDeviation, zDeviation;
      double xFirst, yFirst, zFirst;
      double xLast, yLast, zLast;
      unsigned char edge;
      unsigned char facet;
      unsigned char scanDirection;
      unsigned char intensity;

      PULSEreadOpener pOpener;
      PULSEreader *pReader;
      PULSEscanner scanner;

      GPS();

      void setGPSInformation();
      void writeToFileGPSInformation(std::string fileName);

    };
    #endif /* GPS_HPP_ */ 

This is my GPS.cpp class: 

    #include <iostream>
#include "GPS.hpp"

//Default constructor
GPS::GPS(){
  // enter default values
  xAnchor = 0;
  yAnchor = 0;
  zAnchor = 0;
  xTarget = 0;
  yTarget = 0;
  zTarget = 0;
  xFirst = 0;
  yFirst = 0;
  zFirst = 0;
  xLast = 0;
  yLast = 0;
  zLast = 0;
  edge = 0;
  facet = 0;
  scanDirection = 0;
  intensity = 0;
}


void GPS::setGPSInformation(){

  gpsTime = pReader->pulse.get_t();
  // Compute anchor, target and direction
  pReader->pulse.compute_anchor_and_target_and_dir();
  xAnchor = pReader->pulse.get_anchor_x();
  yAnchor = pReader->pulse.get_anchor_y();
  zAnchor = pReader->pulse.get_anchor_z();
  xTarget = pReader->pulse.get_target_x();
  yTarget = pReader->pulse.get_target_y();
  zTarget = pReader->pulse.get_target_z();
  // Compute first and last returning Values
  pReader->pulse.compute_first_and_last();
  xFirst = pReader->pulse.get_first_x();
  yFirst = pReader->pulse.get_first_y();
  zFirst = pReader->pulse.get_first_z();
  xLast = pReader->pulse.get_last_x();
  yLast = pReader->pulse.get_last_y();
  zLast = pReader->pulse.get_last_z();

  edge = pReader->pulse.edge_of_scan_line;
  scanDirection = pReader->pulse.scan_direction;
  facet = pReader->pulse.mirror_facet,
  intensity = pReader->pulse.intensity;
}

/*
 * Writes all GPS information to a csv file
 */
void GPS::writeToFileGPSInformation(std::string fileName){
  long long pulseIndex = 0;
  FILE *scanout;
  scanout = fopen("gps.csv", "w");
  fprintf(scanout, "Pulse Index, GPS Time, X Anchor, Y Anchor,  Z Anchor, \
                    X Target, Y Target, Z Target, X First, \
                    Y First, Z First, X Last, Y Last, Z Last, \
                    edge, Scan Direction, facet, intensity\n");

  pOpener.set_file_name(fileName.c_str());
  pReader = pOpener.open();

  pReader->seek(0);
  while(pReader->read_pulse()) {
    gpsTime = pReader->pulse.get_t();

    pReader->pulse.compute_anchor_and_target_and_dir();
    xAnchor = pReader->pulse.get_anchor_x();
    yAnchor = pReader->pulse.get_anchor_y();
    zAnchor = pReader->pulse.get_anchor_z();
    xTarget = pReader->pulse.get_target_x();
    yTarget = pReader->pulse.get_target_y();
    zTarget = pReader->pulse.get_target_z();

    pReader->pulse.compute_first_and_last();
    xFirst = pReader->pulse.get_first_x();
    yFirst = pReader->pulse.get_first_y();
    zFirst = pReader->pulse.get_first_z();
    xLast = pReader->pulse.get_last_x();
    yLast = pReader->pulse.get_last_y();
    zLast = pReader->pulse.get_last_z();

    edge = pReader->pulse.edge_of_scan_line;
    scanDirection = pReader->pulse.scan_direction;
    facet = pReader->pulse.mirror_facet,
    intensity = pReader->pulse.intensity;

    fprintf(scanout, "%lld,%.8lf,   \
                      %lf,%lf,%lf,  \
                      %lf,%lf,%lf,  \
                      %lf,%lf,%lf,  \
                      %lf,%lf, %lf, \
                      %d,%d,%d,%d,\n", 
            pulseIndex, gpsTime, 
            xAnchor, yAnchor, zAnchor, 
            xTarget, yTarget, zTarget,
            xFirst, yFirst, zFirst,
            xLast, yLast, zLast, 
            edge, scanDirection, facet, intensity) ;
    pulseIndex++;
  }
}
```

This is my GPS.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GPS.hpp"

//Default constructor
GPS::GPS(){
  // enter default values
  xAnchor = 0;
  yAnchor = 0;
  zAnchor = 0;
  xTarget = 0;
  yTarget = 0;
  zTarget = 0;
  xFirst = 0;
  yFirst = 0;
  zFirst = 0;
  xLast = 0;
  yLast = 0;
  zLast = 0;
  edge = 0;
  facet = 0;
  scanDirection = 0;
  intensity = 0;
}


void GPS::setGPSInformation(){

  gpsTime = pReader->pulse.get_t();
  // Compute anchor, target and direction
  pReader->pulse.compute_anchor_and_target_and_dir();
  xAnchor = pReader->pulse.get_anchor_x();
  yAnchor = pReader->pulse.get_anchor_y();
  zAnchor = pReader->pulse.get_anchor_z();
  xTarget = pReader->pulse.get_target_x();
  yTarget = pReader->pulse.get_target_y();
  zTarget = pReader->pulse.get_target_z();
  // Compute first and last returning Values
  pReader->pulse.compute_first_and_last();
  xFirst = pReader->pulse.get_first_x();
  yFirst = pReader->pulse.get_first_y();
  zFirst = pReader->pulse.get_first_z();
  xLast = pReader->pulse.get_last_x();
  yLast = pReader->pulse.get_last_y();
  zLast = pReader->pulse.get_last_z();

  edge = pReader->pulse.edge_of_scan_line;
  scanDirection = pReader->pulse.scan_direction;
  facet = pReader->pulse.mirror_facet,
  intensity = pReader->pulse.intensity;
}

/*
 * Writes all GPS information to a csv file
 */
void GPS::writeToFileGPSInformation(std::string fileName){
  long long pulseIndex = 0;
  FILE *scanout;
  scanout = fopen("gps.csv", "w");
  fprintf(scanout, "Pulse Index, GPS Time, X Anchor, Y Anchor,  Z Anchor, \
                    X Target, Y Target, Z Target, X First, \
                    Y First, Z First, X Last, Y Last, Z Last, \
                    edge, Scan Direction, facet, intensity\n");

  pOpener.set_file_name(fileName.c_str());
  pReader = pOpener.open();

  pReader->seek(0);
  while(pReader->read_pulse()) {
    gpsTime = pReader->pulse.get_t();

    pReader->pulse.compute_anchor_and_target_and_dir();
    xAnchor = pReader->pulse.get_anchor_x();
    yAnchor = pReader->pulse.get_anchor_y();
    zAnchor = pReader->pulse.get_anchor_z();
    xTarget = pReader->pulse.get_target_x();
    yTarget = pReader->pulse.get_target_y();
    zTarget = pReader->pulse.get_target_z();

    pReader->pulse.compute_first_and_last();
    xFirst = pReader->pulse.get_first_x();
    yFirst = pReader->pulse.get_first_y();
    zFirst = pReader->pulse.get_first_z();
    xLast = pReader->pulse.get_last_x();
    yLast = pReader->pulse.get_last_y();
    zLast = pReader->pulse.get_last_z();

    edge = pReader->pulse.edge_of_scan_line;
    scanDirection = pReader->pulse.scan_direction;
    facet = pReader->pulse.mirror_facet,
    intensity = pReader->pulse.intensity;

    fprintf(scanout, "%lld,%.8lf,   \
                      %lf,%lf,%lf,  \
                      %lf,%lf,%lf,  \
                      %lf,%lf,%lf,  \
                      %lf,%lf, %lf, \
                      %d,%d,%d,%d,\n", 
            pulseIndex, gpsTime, 
            xAnchor, yAnchor, zAnchor, 
            xTarget, yTarget, zTarget,
            xFirst, yFirst, zFirst,
            xLast, yLast, zLast, 
            edge, scanDirection, facet, intensity) ;
    pulseIndex++;
  }
}
```

This is a driver class that I'm currently using to write the GPS information to a csv.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CmdLine.hpp"
#include "ScannerInformation.hpp"
#include "GPS.hpp"


using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

  CmdLine cmdLineArgs;
  cmdLineArgs.parse(argc,argv);

  if(cmdLineArgs.printUsageMessage == true){
    std::cout << cmdLineArgs.getUsageMessage() << std::endl;
  }
  else{
    std::string fileName = cmdLineArgs.getInputFileName();
    ScannerInformation scannerInfo;
    scannerInfo.writeToFileScannerInformation(fileName);

    GPS gpsInfo;
    gpsInfo.writeToFileGPSInformation(fileName);

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Apart from writing the GPS information to a CSV, I want to be able to access each Wave's gps information in my driver class (something like this) -

```
std::cout << wave.gpsInfo.xAnchor;
```

How do I write my Wave.hpp and cpp so that it has a GPS object as its member variable, and then how do I access the gps information of a wave object from my driver file?

```
#include "GPS.hpp"

class Wave {    
private:
  GPS gps;

public:
 //What kind of methods would I use here?
};
```

Comment: `private:` , `public:` at global scope??

Comment: This does not come close to compiling. Is this your real code? Have a look at [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new to stackoverflow and c++ and I'm still figuring things out on the fly. I have edited the question to be more on point and included additional code. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer the title.

You just do it! An example:

```
struct Pos
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};

struct Line
{
    Pos start;
    Pos end;
};
```

Some notes:

1. Both `Pos` and `Line` are classes. Don't let the keyword `struct` fool you. Since neither have a class-invariant, their data can be public.
2. Don't write a constructor unless you have to. Initialization of members can be done in the class.
3. C++ has value semantics; this means that types generally behaves
   like an int does, no special handling to differentiate between objects and other
   types.

Comment: Upvoted because of the idea of using structs in this case.

Answer (score 0):

To get exactly the code your asking for in your questions, you'd need to make the members publicly available. That's best done with a struct, because it's members are public by default.

```
struct Wave {
  GPS gpsInfo;
};

struct GPS {
  double gpsTime;
  double xAnchor; //you may want to use a Point class or struct
  ...
  unsigned char intensity;
};
```

This way you don't need any extra methods (i.e. getters and setters). There's nothing wrong with that approach, but you basically lose the possibility to add functionality like sanity checks for inputs. If Wave or GPS has a more complex state and members depend on each other's values, you may want to use classes and encapsulate access to their members by using getters and setters.

Comment: classes can also be defined using the struct keyword

Comment: @weeska My question was really vague and I left out a lot of code initially. Sorry about that. I have since edited it so its way clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines:

```
#include "GPS.hpp"
#include "OutgoingWave.hpp"
#include "IncomingWave.hpp"

class Wave {    
private:
  GPS _gps;
  OutgoingWave _ow;
  IncomingWave _iw;    
public:
  const GPS& gps() const { return _gps; }
  const OutgoingWave& ow() const { return _ow; }
  const IncomingWave& iw() const { return _iw; }
};
```

Ensure that returned references don't outlive the `Wave` object (if that's the case, return values, but that will incur additional copying). Classes `GPS`, `IncomingWave` and `OutgoingWave` can be transformed into `struct`s in order to have default public access to all members. By the way, the code you posted does not compile, `public` and `private` modifiers need to be within a class.